# Helmfile combined with subcharts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I currently have a parent helm chart that contains one subchart. The only reason actually I'm using the parent chart, is because it contains a _helpers.tpl file with useful templates that I want to share across my subcharts (once I have more), for example, a template helper for a service yaml. However, for some reason the subchart custom values files are not applied correctly, although they contain valid yaml and are referenced correctly. Also, `helmfile template` actually used to produce valid yamls until I created multiple values files and moved them to the values folder. This is the helmfile:

```
environments:
  local:
  production:

---

releases:
  - name: my-app
    chart: ./parent-chart
    values:
      - ./parent-chart/values.yaml
      - ./parent-chart/charts/child-chart/values/common.yaml
      - ./parent-chart/charts/child-chart/values/local.yaml
```

More specifically, the error occurs when referencing `{{ .Values.image.repository }}`, because it says it can't find the image definition, although it is in the common.yaml:

```
image:
  repository: myrepo/myimage
  tag: "1.0.0"
```

Does the helmfile look valid? Or maybe helmfile is not intended to work with subcharts? Anyhow, I would like to find a way to share templates between multiple charts. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't try to combine an "umbrella" chart with Helmfile.  Can you invert the dependency, so that what you currently have as the "child" chart is standalone, and depends on the "parent" library chart to get the helpers?  You may be hitting a problem around Helm in general where templates in dependencies get values that are limited to the corresponding block in the top-level values; if the child chart references `.Values`, it's what is in the combined values structure under `child-chart:`.

Comment: @DavidMaze how would you invert the dependency? can you show an example please?

Comment: List what you now have as `child-chart` in the `helmfile.yaml`.  In its `Chart.yaml` (or `requirements.yaml`) declare a normal [Helm dependency](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-dependencies) on what is now `parent-chart`, and remove `parent-chart`'s dependency on `child-chart`.  Anything that's in a `{{ define }}` template in the current parent will still be accessible using `include` or `template`.